# How to call get method from a class in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using class data model in Angular 2.

In my Home component, I'm receiving data from a server and storing in that classes.

My question is, I have now the get methods created, like:

```
@Injectable()
export class Menu {
  name: string;
  categories: { [name: string]: Category };

  constructor(data: { name: string }) {
    this.name = data.name;
    this.categories = {};

    Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
      if (name !== "name") {
        this.categories[name] = new Category(data[name]);
      }
    });
  }

  getName(){
    console.log("Menu name: " + this.name);
  }
}
```

How can I call this getName method from my Home component?

In my Home component I have:

```
  getMenus() {
    this.globals.getMenus().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.menus = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
              this.menus[name] = new Menu(data[name]);
        });
        **this.menus.getName();**
        console.log(this.menus);
      },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
  }
```

`this.menus.getName()` throws me an error, it says: **"Property getName() does not exist on type'{[name: string]: Menu;}'"**

However, `console.log(this.menus)` print me all the Menu objects correctly (with field name, and category field (that allows objects of type Category).

[image]

I know probably i'm doing this wrong, but I dont' know any other way to do it.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: add your Home component constructor

Comment: It's because of this line `this.menus[name] = new Menu(data[name]);`. `this.menus` is a map of menus. The error message you've got, exactly states that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `this.menus` is an object, which contains many `Menu's`. But you call your `getName()` on that object which contains `Menus`

You need to call like `this.menus.yourName.getName()`

Comment: Got it! I finally do: this.menus[name].getName();
And it works fine.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just dol like this

get getName(){

```
return this.name;
```

}

your home component:-

import menu component hear

git id
let a = Menu.getName;